# Testing pure ES6 with Karma/Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, karma-runner

I'm starting a pet project with pure ES6, without any transpiler. I'm satisfied with current browser support and don't want all that complexity with Babel and stuff. However Karma doesn't seem to be able to understand ES6 features. Or is it Jasmine?

I get

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

How do I make Karma/Jasmine to understand ES6 syntax/features?

Comment: You need to set up the karma config with babel loader with es2015 preset. As import /export are es6 features karma does not recognize. Either remove the import/export or use require() if you are using nodejs. Or use require JS for module dependency.

Comment: _" I'm satisfied with current browser support and don't want all that complexity with Babel and stuff"_ How is that supposed to work when no current browser supports module loading and you use `import`?

Comment: Technically it is supported and may work in [latest Edge preview](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/17/es6-modules-and-beyond/) - and only there.